# How to include a library in a dll project in visual studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, lib

So I have a project(A) that compiles into a dll file, I then include this dll in another project(B). Now I want to include a library in that dll(A) without having to also include it in the other project(B). How can I do that ?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Do you want to statically link some library into A, but not B? Or is this a third DLL?

Comment: Basically I want the library to be included in my dll

Comment: If project A does not depend on project B you should not have a dependency when using the dll from project A with some other project.

Comment: I have a project that needs to include glfw and then compiles into a dll, I want to be able to import the dll in an other project without it giving me glfw3.h not found error. I hope it is more clear this way

Comment: You can't import it that way. If you need to access glfw directly in the other project you need to include it directly.  If your dll does not expose anything from glfw in the public interface ( and your other project does not want to use glfw directly) than you can remove the dependency.

Comment: So don't include glfw3.h in any header you use in project B, including the ones you use to import stuff from project A.

Comment: What I mean about removing the dependency was the header dependency. The dll dependency will still exist. Meaning if Project A uses glfw then when you use the dll from project A in some other project you still need the glfw dlls regardless if the headers from your dll expose glfw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could link that library statically inside the project(A) DLL. By doing that the binary produced by the library will be include inside the binary of the DLL, project(B) won't be modified at all (if the usage of the statically library won't impact the interface code of the DLL itself, ie: the header included by the project(B).